# How to get Service Provider, not the Network Name

Tags: android

I have an Application (Operator Widget) which Displays the Name of the Network you are currently Connected to.

The Problem is that some Providers either share their Network with others (eg. T-Mobile UK uses 3's Network in some areas) or don't have an own Network and use the one of another Provider (eg. "bob" uses the Network of "A1").

The Problem is that the getNetworkOperatorName() always returns the Name of the Wireless Network (so T-Mobile Users will see 3 as their network...) which confuses Users.
Android itself on the Other hand shows the Service Providers name, what is the Function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getSimOperatorName()